# Установка цвета в View, что использовать вместо getColor()?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Что нужно использовать вместо устаревшего `getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor)`

Студия старательно везде его зачеркивает, но не предлагает альтернативу. 
Минимальный `level` под который идет разработка `API = 9`.

Comment: Попробуй юзать ContextCompat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842983/getresources-getcolor-is-deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте

> `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)`

. Это все равно, что вы будете делать проверку на версию и использовать актуальный для своей версии вариант `getColor`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    ...getResources().getColor(color, theme);
}else {
    ...getResources().getColor(color);
}
```